# Using Jquery .each function in a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am quite new to jquery, and i couldn't use .each function in a php foreach function.
I am trying to do a quantity, unit price, total price table.
I don't know how many table rows does user need, therefore used foreach function. Here is an example what i am trying to do:

my deneme2.php file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width= <script type="text/javascript">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>deneme5.js</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$arr=[1,2];
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val){ ?>
<div>
    <input id="tst1"; type="text"; >
    <input id="tst2"; type="text"; >
    <input id="tst3"; type="text"; > <br><br>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
<input  id="asd"; type="submit"; value="hesapla">
</body>
</html>
```

And my deneme5.js file:

```
$(function(){
    $("#asd").click(function(){

        $("div").each(function(index){

            var a=$("#tst1").val();
            var b=$("#tst2").val();
            var c= parseInt(a)*parseInt(b);
            $("#tst3").val(c);

              });

    });


  });
```

Can you help me? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: jQuery runs in browser, PHP on server.

Comment: What you did here : <script>deneme5.js</script>

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many syntax errors in your code. I have revised it a bit. Please compare it with yours and see where you have your mistakes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- here i have added your javascript code directly. You can include it like that: <script src="deneme5.js"></script>-->
    <script>
    $(function(){
      $("#asd").click(function()  {

        $(".row").each(function(index, element){
          var a = $(element).find(".tst1").val();
          var b = $(element).find(".tst2").val();
          var c = parseInt(a) * parseInt(b);
          $(element).find(".tst3").val(c);
        });

      });
    });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$arr=[1,2];
foreach ($arr as $key=>$val){ ?>
<!-- in the following i have switched your ids into classes because ids have to be unique. Furthermore html attributes do not have to be separated by ';' -->
<div class="row">
    <input class="tst1" type="text">
    <input class="tst2" type="text">
    <input class="tst3" type="text"><br><br>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
<input id="asd" type="submit" value="hesapla">

</body>
</html>
```

One of the things done here was to convert the use of ID's to classes. ID's cannot be duplicated on a page because it will cause problems with JavaScript and CSS.

Comment: Remember - A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: @JayBlanchard - Therefore i have commented my changes in the code.

Comment: I understand @RobinGillitzer, but it has been found that explanations outside of code comments generally work better for folks and makes the answer more searchable.